# Chaining Optional.orElseThrow

Tags: java, functional-programming, option-type

I have a piece of code like this:

```
return getObject()
    .map(obj -> obj.getNullableField())
    .orElseThrow(() -> new IllegalStateException("Object not found!"));
```

At the moment I'm throwing an exception when the given `Object` is not present.

Now I need to also check if the `nullableField` of `Object` is present.

One obvious solution could be something like this:

```
var fieldVal = getObject()
    .map(obj -> obj.getNullableField())
    .orElseThrow(() -> new IllegalStateException("Object not found!"));

  return Optional.ofNullable(fieldVal)
     .orElseThrow(() -> new IllegalStateException("Field is not present"));
```

But I'd like to implement this in the same functional chain...

What am I missing?

Comment: Do you require two different error messages?

Comment: @OleV.V.yes I do

Comment: @davioooh Just a note, your current code would only throw a single `new IllegalStateException("Object not found!")` exception. Even if the object is not null but the attribute within it is null.

Comment: @nullpointer yes, you are right!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It could be implemented within the same chain directly, you would get different exception thrown. Now, it's less readable than your first solution of course, so you have a trade-off.

```
return getObject().map(obj -> Optional.ofNullable(obj.getNullableField())
                                      .orElseThrow(() -> new IllegalStateException("Field is not present")))
                  .orElseThrow(() -> new IllegalStateException("Object not found!"));
```

Comment: I would recommend against nesting (and generally using) optionals, the readability gets slaughtered, but nice answer anyway ;)

Comment: @Lino Indeed, that's why I putted it also as my second sentence. I would recommend a clear separation of invokation and assignation, which builds more maintainable code.

Answer (score 4):

Rather than nesting, I would suggest a simple sequence to solve that as:

```
var value = getObject()
        .orElseThrow(() -> new IllegalStateException("Object not found!"));

return Optional.of(value) // ensured value check already
        .map(CustomObject::getNullableField) // takes care ofNullable
        .orElseThrow(() -> new IllegalStateException("Field is not present"));
```

Comment: This corrects the code in question which would always throw `IllegalStateException("Object not found!")` even if the attribute within the object is `null` and does ensure a sequential check to go further in terms of attributes of entities.

Answer (score 0):

I'd recommend dropping the `Optional` approach completly or at least use it only at the beginning (Imagining that `getObject()` cannot be changed):

```
var value = getObject()
    .orElseThrow(() -> new IllegalStateException("Object not found!"));

var field = value.getNullableField();
if(field == null) {
    throw new IllegalStateException("Field is not present");
}
return field;
```

This doesn't introduce a new `Optional` wrapper just so you can be "fluent" and do it all in a single line / statement.